# How to pattern match on a tuple of generic type? F#

Tags: types, f#, pattern-matching

The function I am trying to implement returns an optimal move from a tictactoe game which inputs a function that returns a type of (GameState -> Player -> Option (Move) * int -> Move)

basically, I need to get the value 'Move' which is defined as

```
type Move = 
            { Row:int; Col:int }
```

```
type Player = Nought | Cross
```

```
type GameState = 
  { Turn: Option<Player>; Size:int; board:Map<int*int, Option<Player>> }
```

As one of the input function returns a tuple of ( Some(optimal move of the type Move), the score associated with the move (integer))

I thought this would work

```
match (MiniMax game.board game.Turn) with
                | (Some({Row = x; Col = y;}), _) -> {Row=x Col=y}
                | (None, _) ->
```

but I get an error message stating; "This expression was expected to have type 'GameState -> Player -> Option (Move) *int'
but here has type a * b'"

How can I match the result from (MiniMaxResult:Option(Move) * int) so I can extract just the type Move??

Two players; nought or cross
and gamestate; contains information about the board actions, size, whose turn

Comment: More context is needed because there is no mention of `GameState` and `Player` types in the code you've provided but there is in the error message

Comment: Updated post, the error message is on the first match pattern..

Comment: I'm sorry to ask you once again but on the first glance, that error message seems to me like some function expects another type or lacks explicit type annotation. Could you also provide a code of your `MiniMax ` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the first thing I see with your code is that you fail due to [partial application](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/partial-application/). Your pattern match expects `Option<Move>*int` but your `MinMaxGenerator` returns returns `GameState -> Player -> Option<Move>*int`. So you have to pass one argument of type `GameState` and one of type `Player` in order to return what you expect. Not sure if it's the only issue though.

Comment: As per my experience compiler messages sometimes can be misleading. But I clearly see that types don't fit and that is included into compiler error message. Also please make sure that you read my updated version because `MinMax` definitely does not need 4 arguments. Instead you need too use those 2 you already have but with correct types.